# Android - Saving upon pause/stop no matter which activity you're on

Tags: android, android-activity, save, sharedpreferences

Despite what state you choose to save in (onPause(), onStop()), where do you put the code so that it saves no matter what activity you're in when you leave?  Main activity?  Any ole' activity and it just somehow knows to implement it from another activity?

I'm looking into using SharedPreferences to save an array of int/bool for my app. I don't see this question answered anywhere.

Comment: Every activity that could alter those values.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but I really figured there was some way to not have to do that(not that copy/paste is such a terrible thing, lol).  I just thought there was another preferred method.  This is a new topic to me.

Comment: @lilgodwin Why not have a base activity class that handles all of that logic, then have your other Activities inherit from that base class?

Comment: That's basically what I'll be doing.  I have a class that holds all my questions/answers (it's a study type app).  I'm writing methods within it to get/set/save/load a copy of the variables.  I just wasn't sure if the method to save has to be written in every state or if there was one central location I could put the method so that it was called no matter where the user is within the app when it closes(pause() or stop()).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reference material for the Activity.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

```
public class CalendarActivity extends Activity {
     ...

     static final int DAY_VIEW_MODE = 0;
     static final int WEEK_VIEW_MODE = 1;

     private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
     private int mCurViewMode;

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences();
         mCurViewMode = mPrefs.getInt("view_mode", DAY_VIEW_MODE);
     }

     protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();

         SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mPrefs.edit();
         ed.putInt("view_mode", mCurViewMode);
         ed.commit();
     }
 }
```

That's off of the Developers site.
Hope this helps a little.